# How do I validate text_field_tag when is not part of the model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a wedding rsvp application and have ran into a problem. I have an RSVP Model with some fields then in my form I have added an extra text field (`text_field_tag`) that does not belong to the RSVP Model, however I want to validate it in my `rsvp.rb` model to make it required.

The extra field is a "code" field (as seen below) that I will be providing in the wedding invitations.

I also want to "compare" the entered "code" in my controller `rsvp_controller.rb` to the valid static code upon rsvp creation.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@rsvp, :html => { class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |r| %>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label pull-left">
    <%= r.label :party, 'Name' %> <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <%= r.text_field :party, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Individual or family name', autofocus: true %>
  </div>
</div>
...
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label pull-left">
    <label for="rsvp_code">Enter code found in invitation</label> <span class="required">*</span>
  </div>
  <div class="control-label">
    <%= text_field_tag 'rsvp_code', nil, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>
...

<% end %>
```

**rsvp_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @rsvp = Rsvp.new(rsvp_params)

  #compare the values of the text field to invitation code
  #if values match then proceed
  #else send error message

  if @rsvp.save
    flash[:success] = 'Thank you'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**rsvp.rb**

```
class Rsvp < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates text_field_tag presence: true #or something like this
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The others answers here will work. But they are very messy. Validations belong on the model.

```
class Rsvp < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :rsvp_code
  validates :rsvp_code, presence: true
end
```

You will also need to change your form from: `<%= text_field_tag 'rsvp_code', nil, class: 'form-control' %>` to `<%= f.text_field :rsvp_code, class: 'form-control' %>`

Read more on [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

Comment: This is great, I like this. Thank you!! Also I added a private method in the model (`rsvp.rb`) to validate that entered code is equal to code provided in invitation!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is not stored in the model, it doesn't make sense to validate it in there. Add this logic in your controller instead. And depending on the way you store your "static code" your controller logic shoud look like this :

```
def create
  if params["rsvp_code"] == "YOUR_CODE"
    Rsvp.new(rsvp_params)
    ...
  else
   flash["error"] = 'Your invitation code does\'t match'
   redirect_to rsvp_new_path
  end
end
```